# Choose betwen a few message values depending on 3 variables

Tags: php, factory-method

This code write out the title and the body of a message depending basically on 3 variables combination.

How could i refactor this nicely?

- a factory pattern? how more precisely?
- a mapping array ? but how?
- defer the conditions to another function WriteOutMessage($moderation, $moderation_state, $Authorship)?
- Try to somehow have the same variable names as the possible combinations values?

  ```
   switch ($moderation_state) {
   case 'draft':
  if ($moderation_state_original == 'draft') {
    if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {

      //Envoi à l'auteur
      $send_to = $author_email;

      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;

    }
    else {
      //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
      $params['node_title'] = '';
      $params['message'] = '';
      $send = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
  else {
    //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
    $params['node_title'] = '';
    $params['message'] = '';
    $send = FALSE;
    break;
  }

  break;
  case 'propose_a_la_relecture':

  if ($moderation_state_original == 'propose_a_la_relecture') {
    if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {
      //Envoi à l'auteur
      $send_to = $author_email;

      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;
    }
    else {
      //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
      $params['node_title'] = '';
      $params['message'] = '';
      $send = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
  else {

    //TODO replace with dosi list
    //retrieve all dosi members

    $send_to = "dd@ue";

    $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Nouvel article proposé à la publication par ' . $author_name . ': ' . $article->label();
    $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')
        ->getString();
    $params['message'] .= " vient d'être proposé à la publication par " . $author_name . ".\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Qu'il en soit remercié pour le temps qu'il contribue ainsi à faire gagner à ses collègues et à tous les AMUsagers.\n";
    $params['message'] .= "N'hésitez pas à faire avancer le workflow en assurant une relecture.\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Un petit pas pour la DOSI, mais à coup sûr un grand pas pour la qualité du service public français.\n";
    $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
        ->getString() . "\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
    break;
  }

  case 'relecture_1_ok':
  if ($moderation_state_original == 'relecture_1_ok') {
    if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {
      //Envoi à l'auteur
      $send_to = $author_email;

      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;
    }
    else {
      //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
      $params['node_title'] = '';
      $params['message'] = '';
      $send = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
  else {


    //TODO replace with dosi list
    $send_to = "gg@gg.fr";

    $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Relecture 1 validée pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . " de " . $author_name;
    $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')
        ->getString() . " de " . $author_name . " vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 1 ok par le relecteur " . $current_user_name;
    $params['message'] .= "\nC'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
        ->getString() . "\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Merci de poursuivre l'effort en assurant la 2eme relecture, dernière étape avant publication.\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
    break;
  }

  case 'relecture_2_ok':

  if ($moderation_state_original == 'relecture_2_ok') {
    if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {
      //Envoi à l'auteur
      $send_to = $author_email;

      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;
    }
    else {
      //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
      $params['node_title'] = '';
      $params['message'] = '';
      $send = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
  else {
    //retrieve all rédacteur en chef
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
    $nids = $query->execute();
    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
      $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($nid);
      if ($user->hasRole('redacteur_en_chef')) {
        $emails_redacteur_en_chef[] = $user->getEmail();
      }
    }
    $send_to = implode(',', $emails_redacteur_en_chef);

    $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Relecture 2 ok pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . " de " . $author_name;
    $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')
        ->getString() . " de " . $author_name . " vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 2 ok par le relecteur " . $current_user_name;
    $params['message'] .= "\nC'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
        ->getString() . "\n";
    $params['message'] .= "El Dioudolo.";
    break;
  }

  case 'published':

  if ($moderation_state_original == 'published') {

    if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {

      //retrieve all rédacteur en chef
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
      $nids = $query->execute();
      foreach ($nids as $nid) {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($nid);
        if ($user->hasRole('redacteur_en_chef')) {
          $emails_redacteur_en_chef[] = $user->getEmail();
        }
      }
      $send_to = implode(',', $emails_redacteur_en_chef);
      $send_to .= ',';
      $send_to .= $author_email;


      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;
    }
    else {
      //retrieve all rédacteur en chef
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
      $nids = $query->execute();
      foreach ($nids as $nid) {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($nid);
        if ($user->hasRole('redacteur_en_chef')) {
          $emails_redacteur_en_chef[] = $user->getEmail();
        }
      }
      $send_to = implode(',', $emails_redacteur_en_chef);

      $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
      $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')
          ->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
      $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
          ->getString() . "\n";
      $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
      $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
      break;
    }
  }
  else {
    // $send_to=$article->getOwner()->getEmail();
    //TODO replace with dosi list
    $send_to = "zz@zz";

    $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Nouvel article publié par ' . $author_name . ": " . $article->label();
    $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')
        ->getString() . " de" . $author_name . " vient d'être publié.\n";
    $params['message'] = "Un grand merci collectif à l'auteur: " . $author_name . ". La DOSI l'aime. Ses colllègues l'aiment. AMU entière l'aime. Gloire à toi " . $author_name . " !!!";
    $params['message'] .= "\nPrécipitez-vous: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
        ->getString() . "\n";
    $params['message'] .= "Merci à tous pour votre participation. \n";
    $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
    break;
  }

  case 'mise_a_jour_necessaire':
  //TODO replace with dosi list
  $send_to = "dd@dd.fr";

  $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Mise à jour souhaitée pour: ' . $article->label();
  $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')->getString();
  $params['message'] .= " crée par " . $author_name . " ";
  $params['message'] .= "nécessite une mise à jour. \nUn cycle de relecture est nécessaire avant sa remise en publication:\n";
  $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')
      ->getString() . "\n";
  $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
  $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
  break;

  default:
  //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
  $params['node_title'] = '';
  $params['message'] = '';
  $send = FALSE;
  break;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would rewrite the code to be a lot more read- and maintainable.

The most important point was the D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself) which was already pointed out by @mickmackusa

When you have larger texts with variables make use of the [heredoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

If you have a return/break/continue/exit/die in an if construct you don't need the else

example:

```
<?php
if ($somevalue === true) {
    if ($someOtherValue === true) {
        foo();
        return 3;
    } else {
        bar()
        return 2;
    }
} else {
    baz();
    return 3;
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
<?php
if ($somevalue === true) {
    if ($someOtherValue === true) {
        foo();
        return 3;
    }
    bar();
    return 2;
}
baz();
return 3;
```

Also try to use === and !== instead of == and != whenever possible

Here is the refactored code (~70 lines less):

```
<?php
function getChiefRedactorEmailAddresses(): array{
    $emails_redacteur_en_chef = [];
    //retrieve all rédacteur en chef
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
    $nids = $query->execute();
    foreach ($nids as $nid){
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($nid);
        if ($user->hasRole('redacteur_en_chef')){
            $emails_redacteur_en_chef[] = $user->getEmail();
        }
    }
    return $emails_redacteur_en_chef;
}

// convenience variable to make code/messages more readable
$article_detail_url = $base_url . '/node/' . $article->get('nid')->getString();
$article_title = $article->get('title')->getString();
$article_label = $article->label();

// since the exact same title is used 6 times, we can safely assign it only once to make the code more readable
$node_title_mod = "[DUD] Modifications de $current_user_name pour l'article $article_label de $author_name";

// this message is used twice
$message_mod = <<<EOF
$current_user_name vient de modifier l'article $article_title sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...
C'est là: $article_detail_url
A Bientôt,
Le Dioude.
EOF;

// set the default values here so we can remove this assignment from all the else statements
$params['node_title'] = '';
$params['message'] = '';
$send = false;

switch ($moderation_state) {
    case 'draft':
        if ($moderation_state_original === 'draft' && $current_user_name !== $author_name) {
            //Envoi à l'auteur
            $send_to = $author_email;
            $params['node_title'] = $node_title_mod;
            $params['message'] = $message_mod;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 'propose_a_la_relecture':
        if ($moderation_state_original === 'propose_a_la_relecture') {
            if ($current_user_name !== $author_name) {
                //Envoi à l'auteur
                $send_to = $author_email;
                $params['node_title'] = $node_title_mod;
                $params['message'] = $message_mod;
                break;
            }
            //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
            break;
        }
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        //retrieve all dosi members

        $send_to = "dd@ue";

        $params['node_title'] = "[DUD] Nouvel article proposé à la publication par $author_name: $article_label";
        $params['message'] = <<<EOF
L'article $article_title vient d'être proposé à la publication par $author_name
Qu'il en soit remercié pour le temps qu'il contribue ainsi à faire gagner à ses collègues et à tous les AMUsagers.
N'hésitez pas à faire avancer le workflow en assurant une relecture.
Un petit pas pour la DOSI, mais à coup sûr un grand pas pour la qualité du service public français.
C'est là: $article_detail_url
Le Dioude.
EOF;
        break;

    case 'relecture_1_ok':
        if ($moderation_state_original === 'relecture_1_ok') {
            if ($current_user_name != $author_name) {
                //Envoi à l'auteur
                $send_to = $author_email;

                $params['node_title'] = $node_title_mod;
                $params['message'] = <<<EOF
$current_user_name vient de modifier l'article $article_title sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...
C'est là: $article_detail_url
A Bientôt,
Le Dioude.
EOF;
                break;
            }
            //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
            break;
        }
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "gg@gg.fr";

        $params['node_title'] = "[DUD] Relecture 1 validée pour l'article $article_label de $author_name";
        $params['message'] = <<<EOF
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 1 ok par le relecteur $current_user_name
C'est là: $article_detail_url
Merci de poursuivre l'effort en assurant la 2eme relecture, dernière étape avant publication.
Le Dioude.
EOF;
        break;

    case 'relecture_2_ok':

        if ($moderation_state_original === 'relecture_2_ok') {
            if ($current_user_name !== $author_name) {
                //Envoi à l'auteur
                $send_to = $author_email;

                $params['node_title'] = $node_title_mod;
                $params['message'] = <<<EOF
$current_user_name vient de modifier l'article $article_title sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...
C'est là: $article_detail_url
A Bientôt,
Le Dioude.
EOF;
                break;
            }
            //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
            break;
        }
        $send_to = implode(',', getChiefRedactorEmailAddresses());

        $params['node_title'] = "[DUD] Relecture 2 ok pour l'article $article_label de $author_name";
        $params['message'] = <<<EOF
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 2 ok par le relecteur $current_user_name
C'est là: $article_detail_url
El Dioudolo.
EOF;
        break;

    case 'published':
        if ($moderation_state_original === 'published') {
            $send_to = getChiefRedactorEmailAddresses();
            if ($current_user_name !== $author_name) {
                // since it's the same message we don't need the extra if here, we can just add the current users email
                // to the send_to array
                $send_to[] = $author_email;
            }
            $send_to = implode(',', $send_to);

            $params['node_title'] = $node_title_mod;
            $params['message'] = <<<EOF
$current_user_name vient de modifier l'article $article_title sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...
C'est là: $article_detail_url
A Bientôt,
Le Dioude
EOF;
            break;
        }
        // $send_to=$article->getOwner()->getEmail();
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "zz@zz";

        $params['node_title'] = "[DUD] Nouvel article publié par $author_name: $article_label";
        $params['message'] = <<<EOF
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être publié.
Un grand merci collectif à l'auteur: $author_name. La DOSI l'aime. Ses colllègues l'aiment. AMU entière l'aime. Gloire à toi $author_name!!!
Précipitez-vous: $article_detail_url
Merci à tous pour votre participation
Le Dioude.
EOF;
        break;

    case 'mise_a_jour_necessaire':
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "dd@dd.fr";

        $params['node_title'] = "[DUD] Mise à jour souhaitée pour: $article_label";
        $params['message'] = <<<EOF
L'article $article_title crée par $author_name nécessite une mise à jour.
Un cycle de relecture est nécessaire avant sa remise en publication:
C'est là: $article_detail_url
A Bientôt,
Le Dioude.
EOF;
        break;
    // no need for a "default:", since it doesn't add anything
}
```

How could you improve this code more? You could use a simple replacement template engine for the email messages and put the texts into individual files.

Example:

Very simple "template engine"

```
<?php
$article_title = 'Best template engine ever';
$author_name = 'Donald Trump';
$article_detail_url = '/some/path/to/article';

$message = include 'includes/messages/some_message.php';
```

some_message.php

```
<?php
return <<<EOF
L'article $article_title vient d'être proposé à la publication par $author_name
Qu'il en soit remercié pour le temps qu'il contribue ainsi à faire gagner à ses collègues et à tous les AMUsagers.
N'hésitez pas à faire avancer le workflow en assurant une relecture.
Un petit pas pour la DOSI, mais à coup sûr un grand pas pour la qualité du service public français.
C'est là: $article_detail_url
Le Dioude.
EOF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a switch block is an advantageous design because you are evaluating `$moderation_state` just once.

I think the only aspect of your code worth refining is the repeated `... $send = FALSE;...` parts.  It just isn't as D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself) as it could be.

I recommend pulling all of those `else` portions out of the switch block and running a single `if($send_to){}` after the switch block to handle all disqualified cases.  Notice that you will need to slightly tweak the `if/elseif/else` expressions to maintain accuracy.

Something like this:

```
switch ($moderation_state) {
    case 'draft':
        if ($moderation_state_original == 'draft' && $current_user_name != $author_name) {
            //Envoi à l'auteur
            $send_to = $author_email;
            $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
            $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
            $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')->getString() . "\n";
            $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
            $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude."; 
        }
        break;
    case 'propose_a_la_relecture':
        if ($moderation_state_original == 'propose_a_la_relecture' && $current_user_name != $author_name) {
            //Envoi à l'auteur
            $send_to = $author_email;
            $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
            $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
            $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')->getString() . "\n";
            $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
            $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
            break;
        } elseif ($moderation_state_original != 'propose_a_la_relecture') {
            //TODO replace with dosi list
            //retrieve all dosi members
            $send_to = "dd@ue";
            $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Nouvel article proposé à la publication par ' . $author_name . ': ' . $article->label();
            $params['message'] = "L'article " . $article->get('title')->getString();
            $params['message'] .= " vient d'être proposé à la publication par " . $author_name . ".\n";
            $params['message'] .= "Qu'il en soit remercié pour le temps qu'il contribue ainsi à faire gagner à ses collègues et à tous les AMUsagers.\n";
            $params['message'] .= "N'hésitez pas à faire avancer le workflow en assurant une relecture.\n";
            $params['message'] .= "Un petit pas pour la DOSI, mais à coup sûr un grand pas pour la qualité du service public français.\n";
            $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')->getString() . "\n";
            $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
            break;
        }
    case 'relecture_1_ok':
        if ($moderation_state_original == 'relecture_1_ok' && $current_user_name != $author_name) { 
            //Envoi à l'auteur
            $send_to = $author_email;
            $params['node_title'] = '[DUD] Modifications de ' . $current_user_name . ' pour l\'article ' . $article->label() . ' de ' . $author_name;
            $params['message'] = $current_user_name . " vient de modifier l'article " . $article->get('title')->getString() . " sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n";
            $params['message'] .= "C'est là: " . $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')->getString() . "\n";
            $params['message'] .= "A Bientôt, \n";
            $params['message'] .= "Le Dioude.";
            break;
        }
        break;
    //... continue the case blocks...
}   
if(!$send_to){
    //pas d'envoi d'e-mails
    $params['node_title'] = '';
    $params['message'] = '';
    $send = FALSE;
    break;
}
```

Regarding a lookup array and writing a custom function, I don't think these design options will improve code maintainability.  Though it may save a few lines of code by separating the declarations from the conditional structures, navigating and updating your code will be more tedious and possibly error-prone.

Using the switch cases will simplify debugging, updating, and will be much more comprehensible to future developers that lay eyes on your work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nick and @mickmackusa i have turned it to ( and i am still opened up to comments :

```
<?php


/**
 * 
 *
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity
 */
function amu_dud_rules_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() !== 'content_moderation_state') {
    return;
  }

  $article_id = $entity->get('content_entity_id')->getString();
  $article = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($article_id);
  if ($article->bundle() !== 'article') {
    return;
  }

  include 'includes/notification/messages.php';
  include 'includes/notification/titles.php';

  global $base_url;
  $article_title = $article->get('title')->getString();
  $article_url = $base_url . "/node/" . $article->get('nid')->getString();

  $author_name = $article->getOwner()->get('field_cn_ldap')->getString();
  $author_email = $article->getOwner()->getEmail();
  $current_user_uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $current_user_name = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($current_user_uid) ->get('field_cn_ldap') ->getString();
  $is_author=($current_user_name == $author_name);

  //retrieve all rédacteur en chef
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user');
  $uids = $query->execute();
  foreach ($uids as $uid) {
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
    if ($user->hasRole('redacteur_en_chef')) {
      $emails_redacteur_en_chef[] = $user->getEmail();
    }
  }
  $emails_redacteur_en_chef = implode(',', $emails_redacteur_en_chef);


  $moderation_state = $entity->get('moderation_state')->getString();
  $moderation_state_original = '';
  if ($entity->original) {
    $moderation_state_original = $entity->original->get('moderation_state') ->getString();
  }
  $is_transition_change=($moderation_state !== $moderation_state_original);

  $send_to = $author_email;
  $params['node_title'] = $title_mod;
  $params['message'] = $message_same_state;
  $send = FALSE;

  switch ($moderation_state) {
    case 'draft':
      if (!$is_transition_change && !$is_author) {
          $send = TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'propose_a_la_relecture':
      if (!$is_transition_change && !$is_author) {
          $send = TRUE;
      }
      elseif ($is_transition_change){
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "blabla";
        $params['node_title'] = $title_prop;
        $params['message'] = $message_prop;
        $send = TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'relecture_1_ok':
      if (!$is_transition_change && !$is_author) {
          $send = TRUE;
      }
      elseif ($is_transition_change){
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "blabla";
        $params['node_title'] = $title_relec1;
        $params['message'] = $message_relec1;
        $send = TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'relecture_2_ok':
      $send_to = $emails_redacteur_en_chef;
      $params['node_title'] = $title_relec2;
      $params['message'] = $message_relec2;
      $send = TRUE;
      break;

    case 'published':
      if (!$is_transition_change) {
        $send_to .= ',';
        $send_to .= $emails_redacteur_en_chef;
        $send = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        //TODO replace with dosi list
        $send_to = "blabla";
        $params['node_title'] = $title_pub;
        $params['message'] = $message_pub;
        $send = TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'mise_a_jour_necessaire':
      //TODO replace with dosi list
      $send_to = "blabla";
      $params['node_title'] = $title_maj;
      $params['message'] = $message_maj;
      $send = TRUE;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  if ($send) {
    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $module = "amu_dud_rules";
    $key = 'state_changed_action';
    $to = $send_to;

    $langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();

    $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);

    if ($result['result'] !== TRUE) {
      drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending notifications.'), 'error');
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t("A notification has been sent to $to"));
    }
  }
}
```

includes/notification/messages.php

```
<?php

$message_same_state = <<<same_state
  $current_user_name vient de modifier l'article $article_title sans changer son état. Allez vite voir...\n
C'est là: $article_url.\n
A Bientôt,\n
Le Dioude.
same_state;

$message_prop = <<<proposed
L'article $article_title vient d'être proposé à la publication par $author_name.\n
Qu'il en soit remercié pour le temps qu'il contribue ainsi à faire gagner à ses collègues et à tous les AMUsagers.\n
N'hésitez pas à faire avancer le workflow en assurant une relecture.\n
Un petit pas pour la DOSI, mais à coup sûr un grand pas pour la qualité du service public français.\n
C'est là: $article_url. \n
Le Dioude.
proposed;

$message_relec1 = <<<relecture1
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 1 ok par le relecteur $current_user_name.\n
C'est là: $article_url.\n
Merci de poursuivre l'effort en assurant la 2eme relecture, dernière étape avant publication.\n
Le Dioude.
relecture1;

$message_relec2 = <<<relecture2
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être passé dans l'état Relecture 2 ok par le relecteur $current_user_name.\n
C'est là: $article_url.\n
El Dioudolo.
relecture2;

$message_pub = <<<published
L'article $article_title de $author_name vient d'être publié.\n
Un grand merci collectif à l'auteur $author_name.\n
La DOSI l'aime. Ses colllègues l'aiment. AMU entière l'aime. Gloire à toi $author_name !!!\n
Précipitez-vous: $article_url.\n
Merci à tous pour votre participation.\n
Le Dioude.
published;

$message_maj = <<<maj
L'article $article_title crée par $author_name nécessite une mise à jour.\n
Un cycle de relecture est nécessaire avant sa remise en publication.\n
C'est là: $article_url.\n
A Bientôt,\n
Le Dioude.
maj;
```